# Updating GMSCameraPosition on GMSMapView position isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have an app that has a map with a lot of markers on it, the app notifies the user whenever he approaches one of the markers. I'm using `Google Maps iOS SDK` for the map, that's mean I use `GMSMapView` for the map view (`mapView`).

I want that when the user opens the app via a notification (tap on a notification) the map's camera will automatically be pointing to the notification's marker.

I've tried to do it like this:

**AppDelegate.m**:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *markerIdentifier=[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"markerIdentifier"];
    GMSMarker *marker=[self markerForIdentifier:markerIdentifier];

    [self.aroundersVC.mapView setSelectedMarker:storeMarker];

    //Important part:
    [self.aroundersVC animateMapToMarkerPosition:storeMarker];

}
```

**AroundersViewController**:

```
-(void)animateMapToMarkerPosition:(GMSMarker*)marker
{
    GMSCameraPosition *currentLocationCameraPosition=[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:marker.position.latitude longitude:marker.position.longitude zoom:16];
    [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:currentLocationCameraPosition];
}
```

But it's not working for some reason, anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @FS.O, please stop deleting and re-asking this same question. This is almost identical to your previous two (now deleted) questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579632/updating-gmsmapviews-camera-position-from-appdelegate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593841/updating-gmsmapviews-camera-position-isnt-working

Comment: @SaxonDruce OK. But do you know why isn't it working?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Maybe try adding some logging of the current lat/lon of the mapview, and the lat/lon you're trying to set to, to see if it's doing what you expect. Also add some logging to all the other locations where you're setting a map position, to see if they might be interfering.

Comment: I've checked it and the logs (lat&long of the camera) are fine. I'm changing the camera position just one time on `-observeValueForKeyPath: ofObject: change: context:` and It's working. Maybe the problem is that it's called from the `AppDelegate.m`?
Note that even when I try to use `mapView: animateToLocation` (without a camera) it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: What are you observing to update the camera from `observeValueForKeyPath`? If you're observing the map's `myLocation` property, then maybe `myLocation` is changing after your call to `animateMapToMarkerPosition`?

Comment: @SaxonDruce I've checked it and it isn't

Comment: @SaxonDruce Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use GMSMapview delegate

```
    -(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
      {

         // Do your stuff here 
      }
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This method isn't being called in `-animateMapToMarkerPosition:`, just on `-observeValueForKeyPath: ofObject: change: context:` (and when the user moves the map). Do you know why?